# How can I remount an ejected and unmounted AudioCD on external USB Bluray drive on Mac?

Tags: usb, mount, blu-ray, audio-cd

I am trying to copy my entire CD collection (roughly 200 disks) to MP3s. I use XLD for that task but after a CD is done ripping it disappears completely from the MacOS (10.14) as if it was not even in the drive.

It is not showed in Finder, not showed in diskutil, not showed in ls /dev. When it is mounted it usually shows at /dev/disk4.

How can I mount the disk without powering external drive (LG Bluray BE14NU40) off and on again? I don't want to kill my drive because of that.

Comment: If you eject then swap CD & close the drawer, does it show in Disk Utility at all? [minor secondary point… why mp3, when aac is better quality for a smaller file?]

Comment: Yes, after disk is swapped it spins down and never shows up in diskutil again unless I power cycle the external drive. Any help with that? To the minor point: rip settings are similar, size is pretty much the same and I'm not audiophile to notice the difference. Regardless what format I use outcome with AudioCD being unmounted is the same. But I'll definitely give AAC a try though. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suspect it's the player itself, then. I've no experience with that model, but if it doesn't show in Disk Utility [**not** terminal's diskutil, that will only show mounted volumes] then the device itself has disconnected.

Comment: BTW... it only happens when I use XLD, never with iTunes. I guess, I have to ditch XLD.

Comment: I've never tried XLD for CD rips, only ever used iTunes, so I can't confirm. I use it for other transcodes, or I use [Max](https://sbooth.org/Max/) sometimes.